# The sequence number jumps by 2

Tags: c#

I am printing out the sequence numbers and it jumps by 2 even though I am incrementing it by only 1.
I have a object TradeSequenceNo with a static variable. 
I am assuming that a1 and b2 will have values 1,2 but I see that it has values 2,4. how can I make sure that I can get only increments by 1 for everytime I call TradeSequenceNo.NextSequanceNo

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class TradeSequenceNo
    {
        private static int sequenceno;
        public string id
        {
            get
            {
                return "NextTradeID";
            }
        }
        public static int NextSequanceNo
        {
            get
            {
                sequenceno++;
                return sequenceno;
            }
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a1 = TradeSequenceNo.NextSequanceNo;
            int b2 = TradeSequenceNo.NextSequanceNo;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you posted behaves as you expect (a1 = 1 and b2 = 2). You must have some other code you're not showing that's causing the problem.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be looking at the values in the debugger, would you?

Comment: As mentioned above, your code works fine. Please post an example demonstrating the behaviour you're seeing. As an aside; side-effects in getter properties *is a bad idea*. It should be a method, not a getter. One major problem is what @Dour pointed out; merely watching that property in a debugger causes the value to change.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you posted is because of the debugger. Every time you check for property value in debugger it will be called resulting in increment of the value. Thus if you visit the same value multiple times in debugger you will get higher number depending upon how many times you checked the variable value. Just execute the following code (without debugging) and you will realize that code is correct and is behaving correctly:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class TradeSequenceNo
    {
        private static int sequenceno;
        public string id
        {
            get
            {
                return "NextTradeID";
            }
        }
        public static int NextSequanceNo
        {
            get
            {
                sequenceno++;
                return sequenceno;
            }
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a1 = TradeSequenceNo.NextSequanceNo;
            int b2 = TradeSequenceNo.NextSequanceNo;
            System.Console.WriteLine(a1);
            System.Console.WriteLine(b2);
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```